# How can i use node.js to get all webpage resource ? such as images and css sheet and javascript

Tags: node.js, header, request

How to use node.js to get all webpage resource ? such as images and css sheet and javascript..

i use

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {method: 'HEAD', host: 'www.baidu.com', port: 80, path: '/'};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  }
);
```

only can get a single file header.

```
{"date":"Fri, 26 Dec 2014 12:41:27 GMT","content-type":"text/html","content-length":"14613","last-modified":"Wed, 03 Sep
 2014 02:48:32 GMT","connection":"Keep-Alive","vary":"Accept-Encoding","set-cookie":["BAIDUID=CC1720480D2B6CCCE857D20A27
B203D3:FG=1; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; max-age=2147483647; path=/; domain=.baidu.com","BAIDUPSID=CC1720480D2B
6CCCE857D20A27B203D3; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; max-age=2147483647; path=/; domain=.baidu.com","BDSVRTM=0; pa
th=/"],"p3p":"CP=\" OTI DSP COR IVA OUR IND COM \"","server":"BWS/1.1","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache","b
dpagetype":"1","bdqid":"0xb6908e1e0000cf99","bduserid":"0","accept-ranges":"bytes"}
```

hope someboby can help me. plz. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the header because you asked for one: `method: 'HEAD'`.  To get an actual web page you want to use method `GET`.

As for getting other resources, you need to parse the resulting page, find out references to external javascript and CSS and images, and perform GET on the links as well, there is no shortcut.

Comment: Thank you！   I think i have another way to solve this problem.   Now. I use chrome extension to get  all resources  information then send these informations to node.js.